# streamReader.ReadToEnd() return just header OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml, streamreader

Please, I want to find a word and replace it with another word in word doccument using openXML

I use this method

```
public static void AddTextToWord(string filepath, string txtToFind,string ReplaceTxt)
    {

     WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);
        string docText = null;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream());
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(docText);
        Regex regexText = new Regex(txt);
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText,txt2);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(docText);         
        wordDoc.Close();
    }
```

but

```
docText
```

return just the head of the page that the xml shema of the document.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding=.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check Your Strings**

If you want to replace a specific word or phrase within your existing content, you may just want to use the `String.Replace()` method as opposed to performing a `Regex.Replace()` which may not work as expected (as it expects a regular expression as opposed to a traditional string). This may not matter if you expect to use regular expressions, but it's worth noting.

**Ensure You Are Pulling The Content**

Word Documents are obviously not as easy to parse as plain text, so in order to get the actual "content", you may have to use [an approach similar to the one mentioned here](https://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/retrieve-the-content-of-microsoft-word-document-using-openxml-and-c/) that targets the `Document.Body` properties instead of reading using a `StreamReader` object :

```
docText = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;
```

**Performing Your Replacement**

With that said, you currently appear to be reading the contents of your file and storing it in a string called `docText`. Since you have that string and know your values to find and replace, just call the `Replace()` method as seen below :

```
docText = docText.Replace(txtToFind,ReplaceTxt);
```

**Writing Out Your Content**

After performing the replacement, you'll just need to write your updated text out to a stream :

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
{
     sw.Write(docText);
}
```

Comment: but before using Regex.Replace() i get only header in docText

Comment: Try explicitly targeting the `Body` of your document via : `var docText = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;` or something similar. This should pull the content as opposed to the entire inner document and related XML.